# Store the value of a promise into a variable to use later with state. (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
const storage = AsyncStorage.getItem('@location_data').then(data => data)
const App = () => {
    const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState(storage);
```

Storage currently holds a promise, how could I get storage to become the value of the promise?

[AsyncStorage Documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/)

Comment: Hi Devin, that output does not look like a promise? It appears to be an object as is expected by the code provided. A promise is of the structure:  { <state>: "", <value>: "" }

Comment: When I use .then() on the getItem method it returns the value. That is why i am confused.

Comment: Can you please clarify that in your question? How are you using "then()", and where?

Comment: Sure one moment I will add an example. Im not using it but it does return the correct value.

Comment: Alrighty it is there now.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What are you expecting the data to be? The outer console log is synchronous, so it's not going to wait for the Promise that `getMyStringValue` returns to resolve. Perhaps you should just include the code you are actually having an issue with, i.e. the code where you try to fetch this data and store it in component state.

Comment: Im going to restructure the post, I agree it is vague currently.

Comment: Have you tried an `async` lazy initializer, something like `useState(async () => await AsyncStorage.getItem('@location_data'))`? I'm not 100% sure that would work (I'm not even 50% sure as I don't think any hook callback can be `async`), and if it doesn't then you should use an `useEffect` to fetch and set state when the component mounts.

Comment: The problem with use effect is the routing looks wonky when the app is started. Might have to restructure my code. I'll give your other suggestion a shot.

Comment: Lazy initializer doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (as of writing), is setting **storage** as a promise, your state will now contain a promise. The way you have the **then(data => data)** is doing nothing to your data except adding a (redundant) chain to the promise.

You either need to *await* the promise to finish inside an async function.

```
const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@location_data');
const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState(data);
```

Or, set the state of the promise within *then()*:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('@location_data').then(data => {
    setLocationData(data)
})
```

Comment: I believe setting setLocationData() within a useEffect hook is the only solution for this case.

Comment: Perhaps research "smart/dumb", "presentational/container" component design patterns. It may be best, without more knowledge of your problem, to fetch your location data in a "smart/container" component, and pass that data as a property to the "dumb/presentational" component for display.